# Change a Spinner programmatically in Android

Tags: java, android, view

Im trying to add a Spinner in my app configuration Activity. The spinner offers an option and save it persistently with SharedPreferences.

How can I set the spinner in a position programmatically (for init in the activity creation)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To programatically set the spinner position you should use the method:

`setSelection(position_to_select)`

From the Spinner class (Actually the method's implementation is from the android.widget.AbsSpinner but it is inherited by Spinner class.

You can check the API documentation for it here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html